# Ouput data in JSON format on Array in PHP

Tags: php, json

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
$leaderboard = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $leaderboard[$row["username"]] = $row["score"];
}

$output = array
(
    'status' => 1,
    'content' =>$leaderboard
);

print_r(json_encode($output));
```

right now the `$output` array is such JSON:

```
{"tim":"120","john":"45","larry":"56"}
```

but I want to have them as key-value pair so instead I want to be like:

```
{"name":"tim","score":120","name":"john","score="45", etc.}
```

and if I need that way, how do I modify the `$leaderboard` array so the output would be like that?

Comment: Well, you really can't use duplicate keys... I assume you want to JSON encode an array of associative arrays?  (Thus making an array of objects...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$leaderboard[] = Array('name' => $row["username"], 'score' => $row["score"]);
```